# Transfer multiple rows from 1 table to another

Tags: php, mysql, database, datatable

I created a new table named Rate for rating posts from my Posts table. The Posts table already has data but Rate is empty. When I create a new post, its ID is added to Rate but there are many posts not added that were published before the Rate table.

What sort of query can I use to transfer multiple rows from Posts (just the ids) to the Rate table?

Comment: Why are you doing this? If `rate` has a 1:1 relationship with `Posts` why not just add a new column to the `Posts` table?

Comment: I want to keep them separate to have everything organized and Posts already has a lot of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MySQL [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) for inserting data from one table to another. e.g.:

```
 INSERT INTO Rate (ID, col1, col2) SELECT ID, somecol1, somecol2 FROM Posts WHERE ....
```